# Present nth View Controller without showing its root VC

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have 3 controllers (A, B, C). A and C is ViewControllers, B is NavigationController. Normal application flow is A as root view, A present (modal) B, B push C.
What I want is to present C as top view controllers without going through all the animation from A-B-C but still have the hierarchy (means C can go back to A), is it possible?

We can set window rooViewController directly to C but it wont have the hierarchy

**EDIT:**
Maybe my question isnt clear enough, the main point here is, when I open my app, I want to show C directly but still have A->B->C view hierarchy so I can go back to A via normal pop and dismiss

**EDIT2:**
I manage to show C with B-C hierarchy, so I can pop back to B from C. Now my problem is how can I **present** B (NavigationController) from A (ViewController) so when I close B it will **dismiss* to A

**EDIT3:**
I saw some answer that use NavigationController, it works **BUT** not what I want because normally from A to B I use modal `presentViewController` and from B to A I use `dismissViewController`

**EDIT4:**
So far what I got is

```
self.window.rootViewController = vcA;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[vcA presentViewController:vcB animated:NO completion:nil];
[vcB pushViewController:vcC animated:NO];
```

this will give correct hierarchy that I want but it give fast animation (a blink) showing A and than C and also give warning `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <vcA: 0x7fcfa0cf9c50>.`

**EDIT5:**
I endup ignoring the warning and stick with my prev answer (but still welcome for another solution). And for the blinking problem I use workaround below

```
uiview *overlay = [new uiview]; // using vcA.frame
overlay.backgroundColor = white; // I use dominant color of vcC 
vcA addSubview:overlay;
self.window.rootViewController = vcA;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[vcA presentViewController:vcB animated:NO completion:^{
    [overlay removeFromSuperview];
}];
[vcB pushViewController:vcC animated:NO];
```

This will disguise the blinking behavior so no one will notice (I hope :-p)

Comment: Do you directly want to go to C from A?

Comment: normally I will set the rootView with A (when I open my app) and go to C with the flow that I mention in my question, but there are cases that I need to show C directly when I open my app and still have the hierarchy

Comment: you can extract the view controller from navigation controller stack and do what ever you want to

Comment: referring to your EDIT4 be careful that `pushViewController` could (likely) be called before `presentViewController` has finished. See my answer edit to see how to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [UINavigationViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:) and then call

```
setViewControllers(_:animated:)
```

> > Use this method to update or replace the current view controller stack without pushing or popping each controller explicitly. In
> >     addition, this method lets you update the set of controllers without
> >     animating the changes, which might be appropriate at launch time when
> >     you want to return the navigation controller to a previous state.
>
> If animations are enabled, this method decides which type of
>   transition to perform based on whether the last item in the items
>   array is already in the navigation stack. If the view controller is
>   currently in the stack, but is not the topmost item, this method uses
>   a pop transition; if it is the topmost item, no transition is
>   performed. If the view controller is not on the stack, this method
>   uses a push transition. Only one transition is performed, but when
>   that transition finishes, the entire contents of the stack are
>   replaced with the new view controllers. For example, if controllers A,
>   B, and C are on the stack and you set controllers D, A, and B, this
>   method uses a pop transition and the resulting stack contains the
>   controllers D, A, and B.

Let me know if it help you :)

Comment: this isn't what he asked for .. ;) a presents b and b pushes c ... a & c are NOT the same navi so this doesn't apply

Comment: and just citing docs often doesn't work ;) please provide at least a word of your own

Answer (score 1):

push A and B and C like you normally would but do it by using `presentViewController:? animated:NO` and `pushViewController:? animated:NO` -- not animating is the clue

e.g. (mock code)

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching {
    id a = [MyA new]; //root, presents b
    id b = [MyA new]; //pushes c you said.. so it is or has a navigationController
    id c = [MyA new];

    [a presentViewController:b animated:NO]; 
    b.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: yes I do exactly like that but it show `Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x7fcf92869400> on <VCA: 0x7fcf91d898b0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!` and A showing as visible VC

Comment: @Ansel: you should create a navigation controller D, and set B controller as root controller of that D. Then you present D not B controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just present C on top of A with `presentViewController`?

**EDIT:**

*A -> C:*

In vcB I would add a boolean property indicating whether we are in the mentioned flow and present vbB in vcA this way:

```
// We are in vcA where you want to present vcB and vcC
vcB.transient = YES;
[vcA presentViewController:vcB animated:NO completion:^{
    [vcB pushViewController:vcC animated:NO];
}];
```

*C -> A*

When you want to go back to vcA, popping vcC will call `viewDidAppear` in vcB.

```
// We are in vcB
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if(self.transient == YES) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        return;
    }
}
```

With this solution when you go back from vcC to vcA you will temporary see vcB, as we have to wait for `viewDidAppear` to be called.

**EDIT 2:**

Alternatively if you don't need to directly go back from vcC to vbA, just use the first piece of code (no transient property required).

Comment: well, it doesnt fit my requirement because if I present C on top of A then C wont be able to go to B.

Comment: ok, you didn't say that in the backward direction you want to pass through B as well. In this case you could presentViewController with no animation and in the completion block push C.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize, in fact I added a solution proposal. To be clearer  I've edited my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: nope, I already tried this and I notice the one that give warning isnt `presentVC` but `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`, I present vcB before vcA visible

Answer (score 0):

Keep A as rootVC(in applicationDidFinishLaunching). So when you open your app it will load A first.

Once A is loaded(in viewDidLoad) call a method to present B(keep animation = NO while presenting).

When B is loaded, call a method to push to C(keep animation = NO while pushing).

Hope this helps!

Comment: this works but why should one wait for viewDidLoad ?

Comment: i need to show C in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` so using `viewDidLoad` wont be possible

Comment: The end user will feel like C is the first screen(make sure the animation when presenting/pushing). If you want to make A as a rootVC then my above mentioned steps can achieve this functionality. "viewDidLoad" is required because the view should be loaded in the stack of ViewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

To segue to any ViewController you want to: Have you drawn a custom segue in the storyboard by holding down the control key on your keyboard and clicking the ViewController you want the segue to be in? While still holding control, you can drag it to the viewcontroller you want to segue to. After that just let go and XCode will let you choose the type of segue you want: `push`, `modal`, or `custom`.

[image]

After that, click the visual segue reference that Xcode creates (looks like a big grey arrow in the storyboard that points to your viewcontrolelrs) and click the attributes inspector. Then look where it says `identifier`. From there you can name the segue anything you want and reference it programmatically. Just do the above and call the below message and you should be able to go to any viewcontroller when ever you want to.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowViewControllerA" sender:self];
```

Also, I agree with everyone else saying to set Viewcontroller C as root ViewController in the storyboard. PresentViewController is also a good idea. etc

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Daij-Djan's answer:

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching {
  id a = [MyA new]; //root, presents b
  id b = [MyA new]; //pushes c you said.. so it is or has a navigationController
  nav d = [[Nav alloc] initWithRoot:b];
  id c = [MyA new];

  [a presentViewController:d animated:NO]; 
  b.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: B is already a NavCon, so I don't need another one. In fact, if I use another NC it give me error `'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'`